# Moving window on a Standard Deviation & Mean calculation

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, data-analysis, standard-deviation

I have a `df` which has many columns. I am currently using following command `output = df.join(df.expanding().std().fillna(0).add_prefix("SD"))` to generate a Standard deviation column for column `A` based on cumulative values like this:

```
A   SDA
1       x1
2       x2
3       x3
4       x4
5       x5
```

Where `x1`  is the `SD` of `1`, `x2` is the SD of `1,2` ; `x5` is the SD of `1,2,3,4,5` and so on.
I want to move the window in such a way that after it moves to `11`, the `SD` will be calculated on  the values `2 to 11`.

```
A      SDA
1       x1
2       x2
3       x3
..      ..
9       x9
10      x10
11      x11
12      x12
13      x13
..      ..
20      x20
21      x21
22      x22
```

So, here **x11** will be calculating Standard deviation of values from  `2,3,4..11`and **x12 ** will be of `2 to 12` .Thus, **x20** will be based on `2 to 20`. After 20 values, it will again move one step and **x21** will be the `SD` of ``` 3,4,5,6...21`` . ```x22`will be  based on values from`3 to 21```  and so  on. I want to do such operation for multiple columns and generate multiple  **SD** column at a time.

I am not sure how to use `expanding` function for this kind of moving windows.
For calculating mean in such same way, shall I just use `mean` function in the place of `std()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to determine the lower- and upper-bound for each row, then it's easy:

```py
from datar.all import (
    f, across, c, tibble, mutate, row_number, std, rnorm
)

# Create a example df
df = tibble(A=rnorm(22), B=rnorm(22))

def stdev(col, lower, upper):
    """Calculate the stdev with the lower- and upper-bound of current column"""
    return [std(col[low:up]) for low, up in zip(lower, upper)]

(
    df
    >> mutate(
        # create the lower- and upper-bound
        # note it's 0-based
        upper=row_number(),
        lower=(f.upper - 1) // 10,
    )
    >> mutate(
        across(
            # Apply stdev func to each column except the lower and upper columns
            ~c(f.lower, f.upper),
            stdev,
            lower=f.lower,
            upper=f.upper,
            _names="SD{_col}",
        )
    )
)
```

```
           A         B   upper   lower       SDA       SDB
   <float64> <float64> <int64> <int64> <float64> <float64>
0  -0.399324  0.740135       1       0       NaN       NaN
1  -0.023364  0.468155       2       0  0.265844  0.192318
2   0.839819 -0.899893       3       0  0.635335  0.878940
3  -0.788705  0.497236       4       0  0.695902  0.744258
4   1.838374 -0.153098       5       0  1.053171  0.663758
5   0.174278 -0.938773       6       0  0.943238  0.736899
6   0.265525  1.906103       7       0  0.861060  0.998927
7   0.484971  1.687661       8       0  0.800723  1.058484
8   0.238861  1.378369       9       0  0.749275  1.041054
9   1.068637 -0.075925      10       0  0.747869  0.999481
10 -1.742042 -0.192375      11       1  0.984440  1.013941
11 -0.779599 -1.944827      12       1  0.982807  1.188045
12 -0.478696  0.211798      13       1  0.954120  1.132865
13 -2.598185 -0.747964      14       1  1.179397  1.113613
14 -0.308082  0.171333      15       1  1.134297  1.070135
15  0.700852 -2.719584      16       1  1.113848  1.261954
16  0.917145  0.375815      17       1  1.104229  1.224715
17  1.343796 -0.796525      18       1  1.118582  1.199169
18  1.024335 -0.943663      19       1  1.108354  1.180068
19 -0.877742 -0.431288      20       1  1.101227  1.148623
20 -0.584439 -0.555945      21       2  1.111302  1.141233
21 -0.946391 -1.550432      22       2  1.103871  1.149968
```

You can finally remove the `lower` and `upper` columns using `select()`:

```py
df >> select(~c(f.lower, f.upper))
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), which is a wrapper around `pandas` to implement some features from `dplyr`/`tidyr` in `R`.